# Automatically fetch USD Exchange Rate from API and Update it in Microsoft SQL Database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I want to update a table in a database but I can't even fetch the rate from the API.

I get this error:

> Msg 39007, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_execute_external_script, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 0]
> The specified language 'SQL' does not exist or you do not have permission.

This is the procedure I am using:

```
DECLARE @url NVARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @response NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Set the API URL
SET @url = 'https://www.banxico.org.mx/SieAPIRest/service/v1/series/SF43718/datos/oportuno?token=734b37b3a5099a9d2d39d06478d47e359a9568cd6693116d95b710e6b8be0008';

-- Use built-in SQL Server functions to make HTTP request and obtain response
-- Requires SQL Server 2016 or later
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX);

-- Use sys.dm_exec_query_stats to enable SQL Server to execute external scripts
USE lndb;

EXEC sp_execute_external_script
  @language = N'SQL',
  @script = N'
    DECLARE @winHttpReq INT;
    DECLARE @status INT;

    EXEC sp_execute_external_script
      @language = N''R'',
      @script = N''
        library(httr)
        url <- "https://www.banxico.org.mx/SieAPIRest/service/v1/series/SF43718/datos/oportuno?token=734b37b3a5099a9d2d39d06478d47e359a9568cd6693116d95b710e6b8be0008"
        response <- GET(url)
        status <- status_code(response)
        writeLines(content(response, "text"))
      '',
      @output_data_1_name = N''json'',
      @output_data_1 = @json OUTPUT;

    SELECT @json;
  ',
  @input_data_1 = N'';

-- Parse the JSON response using OPENJSON
DECLARE @usdRate DECIMAL(18, 6);

SELECT @usdRate = value
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.bmx.series[0].datos[0].dato') 
   WITH (value DECIMAL(18, 6) '$');

-- Display the result
SELECT @usdRate AS USDExchangeRate;
```

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-external-script-transact-sql) for `sp_execute_external_script` says:

> Use `sp_execute_external_script` to execute scripts written in a supported language. Supported languages are **Python** and **R** used with Machine Learning Services, and any language defined with [`CREATE EXTERNAL LANGUAGE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-language-transact-sql) (for example, Java) used with Language Extensions.

You have:

```
@language = N'SQL'
```